# Lattice points satisfying multiple variable inequality

Tags: combinatorics, summation, arithmetic

For a given $k \in \mathbb{N}, k\geq 2 $ and for a fixed $r \in \mathbb{N}, r \leq k$, I need to find all positive integers $n_j$ that satisfy:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{r}n_j \geq \sum_{j=1}^{r}k^{n_j-1}\ -2r
$$

Comment: " I need to find all positive integers..." You mean "all sets of $r$ positive integers..." ?

Comment: @leonbloy No, the $n_j$'s, which should be limited by the values of r

Comment: Sorry, I just cannot make sense of this.

Comment: Sorry, maybe if I give an example: For r=2 and k=2 we have that the possible solutions are: $(n_1,n_2) = \{(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(2,2)\}$.